# TypeError: Cannot visit Mail::Multibyte::Chars

Tags: ruby

I recently update the gems on our Gemfile and started getting:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.new(:email => "foob@gmail.com").valid?
TypeError: Cannot visit Mail::Multibyte::Chars
```

User Model tiene:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

If we take the validation off, everything works.

Comment: I have the same thing happening now. I wonder how you fixed it. When i find it, i'll send an update here.

Comment: This was due to a gem overwriting valid? and calling Mail::Multibyte::chars. We had to re-order gem loading. I can't remember which gem.

Comment: dude, you are a genius! I'm going to do what you said and then write the answer below :-) but first i need to be on billable hours then though. A guy has his standards.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue in my Sinatra app and it appeared to be caused by the mail gem. I was able to fix it by requiring 'active_support' before Bundle.require:

```
require 'active_support'

Bundler.require(:default, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I'm a man of my word:

My fix was moving `gem pony` to the last gem loaded in the Gemfile in my Sinatra app.

Cory's solution didn't exist when I tried it, fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with a [Mailman](https://github.com/titanous/mailman) script I was running. I fixed it by running by changing the way the script was run, from:

```
bundle exec script/mailman.rb
```

to

```
bundle exec rails runner script/mailman.rb
```

I suspect I could also have loaded Rails before Mailman in the actual script.